# javascript await on multiple chained async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-2017

Say I have the following:

```
const a = new A();
await a.getB().action();
```

`A.prototype.getB()` is `async` as-well as `B.prototype.action()`.
If I try to await on the chaining of the functions I get an error:
`TypeError: a.getB(...).action is not a function`.

If I am separating the chaining of the functions and awaiting each promise it works fine.
Is there a way to chain these promises and await them together?

Comment: Have you tried `(await a.getB()).action()`?

Comment: Try: `await (await a.getB()).action()` or `await a.getB().then(result => result.action())`

Comment: I was hoping there's some syntatic sugar I could get away with, guess I will have to await for each promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `getB` is an async function and does not return a B object but a `Promise` object that have no `action` method. This promise will further be resolved with a B object and you can access to the resolved value by catching it with the `then` method as proposed by PVermeer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I was just about to make an edit :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to await hem both:

```
const a = new A();
const b = await a.getB();
await b.action();
```

Or

```
const a = new A();
await a.getB().then(b => b.action());
```

Comment: `var` is a keyword, and it will throw a error when you try to run this code `variable name is missing`